# C# with Google Drive embedded

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

Among different features, I want to include Google Drive with my C# application for users to log in and access their drive's files.
I researched a lot of code in this web and from other sources, and I had success with the following one:

```
UserCredential credential;

using (var stream =
    new FileStream("client_id.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
        System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json");

    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        Scopes,
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
    Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
}

// Create Drive API service.
var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
    });

// Define parameters of request.
FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
//listRequest.PageSize = 10;
listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";

// List files.
IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute().Files;
Console.WriteLine("Files:");
if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", file.Name, file.Id);
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No files found.");
}
Console.Read();
```

I had to get my credentials on the web of Google Drive for developers.
This code works well but it means that every user of my application will have to generate their own Google Drive credential manually, and I cannot figure out how to automate this.

My aim is to offer the interface for the user showing two boxes for the input of their Google email and password, then do the work for authentication and if it succeeds, the user would have access to their files.

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to put your content quality up

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of Open Authentication.   For your application to access a users data they must give your application permission to access their data or "authorize it".   The scopes you are sending is what is used to tell the user what permissions you will need in order for your application to run.   They are given a pop up window asking them to authorize your application with these permissions.   Once granted you can access their data.

Asking a user for their login and password to access an account is called client login.  Client login was shut down by google in 2015 it is not possible for you to access their account using a login and password.   You must use Oauth2 and request access like your code is currently doing.

Your code works as it is and it is working as it should.  You cant automate there authorization they must click the it them selves.

Comment: First, thank you for taking your time for reading my problem and answering. After all my research and your answer I see ir more imposible to make my idea real for there is no way now to develop an application that provides an user of accessing his google drive, they'll always be forced to generate the credential of developers for accessing api's features.

Comment: The user only has to approve your application once

Comment: Yes, but that would be the way for the users to interact with only one drive through the application as far as I'm concerned.
My aim, if it's possible to do by Google API's, is that every user log in my aplication, access with his gmail and password (in my application, or in the browser) and then they could see the files in their personal drive in the application in some kind of list. But if i'm understanding this right, the only way for doing that is generating a developer credential for every user, and that's my problem

Comment: When a user authenticates your application you a refresh token for that user.    "user"  is your name for the user associated with the refresh token.   You can have as many users as you want attached to developer credentials.  Developer credentials just identify your application you can have an unlimited number users authenticating your application.

Comment: Yes, I could understand it, but I'm not finding the way for each user to log in the application an watching their personal files of their drives (in a list or something like that). Sorry if I'm driving you crazy or if I'm not clear enough in explaining my aims.
I mean, as I've researched and read your answers the users of my application will read the developer credential of my drive and only will access my files, and I want to every user access their personal drive.